# pandas how to select some values from difference

Tags: python, pandas

How to select values from diff that lie in a certain range?

```
df['timestamp'].diff() # .select(1 < x < 10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `loc` + `lambda`

```
df['timestamp'].diff().loc[lambda x : (x>1) &(x<10)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can obtain the original row in your dataframe where the `diff` is between 1 and 10 like this:

```
df.loc[(df['timestamp'].diff() > 1) & (df['timestamp'].diff() < 10)]
```

Example:

given a `df`:

```
>>> df
   timestamp
0          8
1          4
2          1
3          5
4          3
```

With these `diff()` values:

```
>>> df.diff()
   timestamp
0        NaN
1       -4.0
2       -3.0
3        4.0
4       -2.0
```

You can extract that row where the `diff` is in your range:

```
>>> df.loc[(df['timestamp'].diff() > 1) & (df['timestamp'].diff() < 10)]
   timestamp
3          5
```

**Edit** As pointed out by @Wen, using `diff()` twice is not really so efficient. You can also create a mask using `diff()` and use that mask to extract your rows, along the lines of:

```
msk = df.diff()
df.where((msk > 1) & (msk < 10))
```

Comment: Do diff twice  is slowing down the process , I think create the mask is better : -)

Comment: Yeah, that's true! Thanks!